# AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler_so'

Tags: python, tensorflow, build-error

I'm trying to run some faster r cnn tf code that I got from GitHub. All those code need to run 'make' command to run the Cython (correct me if I am wrong). But everytime I run the make command I always got the same problem for every code.

I'm using windows 10 professional with python 3.5
My tensorflow version is 1.8.0 with gpu and CUDA 9.0

here is the error from the command line :

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 150, in <module>
    cmdclass={'build_ext': custom_build_ext},
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 338, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "setup.py", line 104, in build_extensions
    customize_compiler_for_nvcc(self.compiler)
  File "setup.py", line 77, in customize_compiler_for_nvcc
    default_compiler_so = self.compiler_so
AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler_so'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.compiler_so` field [is only present in `distutils.unixcompiler.UnixCCompiler` and derivatives](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/unixccompiler.py#L57).

So, this package does not support standard Windows build environment.

As per [Build from source on Windows  |  TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows), it's supposed to be built using MSYS2.